# Retrieve Linux command line history by date

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, history

I want to see what I typed on my bash command line on a certain day a week ago. Is there a way to retrieve command line history? Something like below, perhaps?

```
> history --include-date | grep 2012-02-27`
```

Comment: if you're using zsh: `history -E`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

By default, `History` logs the time when you ran a command, but doesn't display it. The reason for this is when you run the `History` command, it looks for an environment variable called `HISTTIMEFORMAT`, which tells it how to format time. If the value is `null` or not set, then by default it doesn't show any time.

An example with some time-

```
[qweet@superbox ~]$ export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %t '
[qweet@superbox ~]$ history
    1  2012-03-06        su -
    2  2012-03-06        jbach@mobiletribe.net
    3  2012-03-06        mysql
    4  2012-03-06        ll
    5  2012-03-06        cd /opt/
    6  2012-03-06        ll
    7  2012-03-06        exit
    8  2012-03-06        ll
    9  2012-03-06        ls -lsa
   10  2012-03-06        cd ../
   11  2012-03-06        ll
   12  2012-03-06        ll
....
```

But that's not all. Since the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` takes `strftime` values (which you can find [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strftime.html) btw), you can do all sorts of magical things. But for what you want to do, the following works.

```
[qweet@superbox ~]$ export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T %t'
[qweet@superbox ~]$ history | grep -e "2012-03-06 14:48"
 1006  2012-03-06 14:48:05      export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T %t'
 1007  2012-03-06 14:48:07      history
 ...
```

Also, if you want your HISTTIMEFORMAT to persist, consider appending it to your `bashrc` like so;

```
echo 'HISTTIMEFORMAT="variables here"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

You will see the changes when you open a new tab in the terminal, or logging out and in.

Comment: Bash doesn't log time by default. If HISTTIMEFORMAT is not set, the command is logged without its time.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the HISTTIMEFORMAT variable will help, but unfortunately only for the future. [This nixCraft article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-bash-history-display-date-time/) explains how to set that variable permanently, but uses an ambiguous date format. For ISO 8601, use:

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%G-%m-%dT%T "
```

Result:

```
$ history
[...]
   13  2022-11-07T13:32:01 pwd
   14  2022-11-07T13:32:05 cd
   15  2022-11-07T13:32:10 ls -l
```

Commands which were run before `HISTTIMEFORMAT` was set will display a bogus time.